# Netbeans wont start

Tags: netbeans

I recently nstalled netbeans 7.2 on my computer(running windows 7) and when I click on the desktop icon/in the taskbar etc netbeans won't start up. I've uninstalled and reinstalled it twice now and am unsure what I should do next.

I have the latest version of Java SDK and it found it. when I hit the log it prints

```
 the launcher has determined that the parent process has a console and will reuse it for its own console output. 

Closing the console will result in termination fo the running program. java.io.FileNotFoundExeption: \lock(access is denied) and Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Think we need more info to help you solve that...

Comment: what would you like to know? when i click the icon, the computer looks like it's doing something for 2 seconds then nothing

Comment: I am downvoting this. You need to give more info on what is happening. "It doesn't work" is not the type of question to ask here.

Comment: it's not starting? there is nothing else I can say because it isn't doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

A downvote seems a bit harsh... Can you run the trace from the command line? From the command line run:

```
netbeans.exe --trace C:\netbeans.log
```

post the log or your solution if you fix it...

Other suggestions from the top of my head are either you need a later version of the Java SDK, the path to the Java SDK is incorrect, your missing an environment variable, or you dont have the memory available to run the IDE? Alternatively corrupted plugins, or user data from a previous installation is causing you problems.. Just suggestions, think you need to provide more info...

Have just downloaded and installed Netbeans 7.2 and it works fine on Win 7, x64

Comment: I have the latest version of Java SDK and it found it. when I hit the log it prints

the launcher has determined that the parent process has a console and will reuse it for its own console output. Closing the console will result in termination fo the running program. 


java.io.FileNotFoundExeption: \lock(access is denied) and Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Have you tried run as administrator? Alternatively a good place to ask this question would be the netbeans forums...

Comment: yeah no luck running it as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, finally this worked with me on version 11.3, delete this folder, then run the program again

```
C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans
```

here my main username is Dell, yours can be different ofcourse